# IB Connections in Xcode crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, ibaction, iboutlet

I was working on my iOS app last night when I went to test it and it crashed on startup. I wasn't even working on the nib that is causing the crash. Anyways, here is the error code:

```
2/29/12 10:32:05.291 AM Safe Flight: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0xdd496f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Airport1.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2873052 0x33add0a 0x2872f11 0x1ae2032 0x1a53f7b 0x1a53eeb 0x1a6ed60 0x136191a 0x2874e1a 0x27de821 0x136046e 0x1362010 0x114214a 0x1142461 0x11417c0 0x1150743 0x11511f8 0x1144aa9 0x37b7fa9 0x28471c5 0x27ac022 0x27aa90a 0x27a9db4 0x27a9ccb 0x11412a7 0x1142a9b 0x3710 0x2f35)
```

Airport1 is just a label with an IBOutlet **correctly** connected to it. Also, if I delete the connection the error just is with the next item that has an connection.

Also, my FileOwners class it correctly set to the appropriate viewController.

```
//  MasterViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MobclixAds.h"

@class DataViewController;
@class EditViewController;
@class SearchViewController;



@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController{

    UILabel *Airport1;
    UILabel *Airport2;
    UILabel *Airport3;
    UILabel *Airport4;
    UILabel *Airport5;
    UILabel *Airport6;
    UILabel *Airport7;
    UILabel *Airport8;
    UILabel *Airport9;
    UIButton *Airport1B;
    UIButton *Airport2B;
    UIButton *Airport3B;
    UIButton *Airport4B;
    UIButton *Airport5B;
    UIButton *Airport6B;
    UIButton *Airport7B;
    UIButton *Airport8B;
    UIButton *Airport9B;

    MobclixAdView* adView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) DataViewController *dataViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) EditViewController *editViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SearchViewController *searchViewController;


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Airport1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Airport2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Airport3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Airport4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Airport5;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Airport6;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Airport7;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Airport8;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *Airport9;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Airport1B;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Airport2B;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Airport3B;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Airport4B;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Airport5B;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Airport6B;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Airport7B;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Airport8B;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Airport9B;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet MobclixAdView* adView;


@end
```

and

```
// MasterViewController.m


#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DataViewController.h"
#import "EditViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"



@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize dataViewController = _dataViewController;
@synthesize editViewController = _editViewController;
@synthesize searchViewController = _searchViewController;



@synthesize Airport1, Airport2, Airport3, Airport4, Airport5, Airport6, Airport7, Airport8, Airport9;
@synthesize Airport1B, Airport2B, Airport3B, Airport4B, Airport5B, Airport6B, Airport7B, Airport8B, Airport9B;
@synthesize adView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Safe Flight";
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

So is my problem with my code? or with Xcode itself?? I have restarted Xcode and the simulator and even did a "clean" build (it sounded like it would help...)

Thanks,
Andrew

**EDIT** This is my AppDelegate and I'm setting the correct xib to the window

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [Mobclix start];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

PROBLEM SOLVED!!!

I can't answer my own question because of some stupid spam filter... and I can post a picture of the problem... but its fixed!

but here is a link to the problem [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krba5.png)

Comment: Look for the xib where your view controller is. Change the class the same way you did with FileOwner.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to say, could you please clarify?

Comment: Did you see that the object generating the error is not the ViewController but UIApplication? Can you post the code where This is being called? What I wanted you to do is the same as the answer given. What I suggest you to do, is find Identity Inspector class not on FileOwner, but in the View Controller itself. Do you declare it in any xib or you create it directly on code?

Comment: Is your View Controller declared in any main xib file, that one where there is a UIWindow on it? If it is, you'll have to change the class name for it as well.

Comment: Is navigationController an ivar? Does it have an outlet to a xib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Problem!! I feel kinda stupid now ;) but anyways, here is a screenshot of the problem!

[image: Devices "Main Interface" had been unintentionally set]

Answer (score 1):

The reason causing to crash could be the connection mistakes within xib to header.
Airport1 could be connected to another class than MasterViewController.

If your label connected to **File's Owner** - it should be **MasterViewController**.

If you've created another UIViewController within xib and connected Airport1 label to it, then this controller also should be connected to **MasterViewController** (**Identity Inspector** "**Class**" field.)

Updated. Added Screenshots:

[image: This is File Owner's]

[image: This is Identity Inspector]

Comment: Thats the weird thing, I have had that problem before and so I checked that and I have the class set to my viewController. It must be something else

Comment: Sorry, I cant guess your problem. It is just the most common mistake. If you check your xib connectors again - I'm sure - you will find the reason.

Comment: I have my class set correctly :/ I wish it was that simple [Screenshot](http://safeflight.boosproductions.com/Untitled.tiff)

Comment: Great. Then check if you have no yellow triangles in Owner's properties (right mouse button). If your labels connects properly. If yes - I have no other ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the MasterViewController (wherever you are launching it from), make sure you are initializing it with the appropriate nib file

Ex.

```
MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: How is your xib setup? Does it just have a "UIView" object with the "File Owners" view outlet set to it. Or did you add a UIViewController to the xib.? If the latter make sure that file has the appropriate class (MasterViewController).